# no-ignore-case in grep command

Tags: bash, shell, grep

In man page of `grep --no-ignore-case` matching control has the following description:

> Do  not  ignore  case  distinctions  in patterns and input data.  This is the default.  This option is useful for passing to shell scripts that already use `-i`, to cancel its effects because the two options override each other.

Please explain it by an example.

Answer (score 1):

Really useful.

Example, you have this alias:

```bash
 alias mygrep='grep -i'
```

or this function:

```bash
mygrep () {
  grep -i "${@}"
}
```

Test:

```bash
$ echo -e 'egg\nEGG' | mygrep egg
egg
EGG

$ echo -e 'egg\nEGG' | mygrep --no-ignore-case egg
egg
```

`--no-ignore-case` cancel the `-i` option.